# iOS map view is missing the pin for a location

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I got a very weird problem when I tried to call iOS map for navigation from current location to a location in my app. The routes were correctly calculated, but the destination location doesn't have a pin in the map, the current location has the pin though. My code is like the following. I think I'm missing something really basic but can't figure out.... Any thoughts?

```
(void) routeInMap
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = [[thisAttraction objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
    location.longitude = [[thisAttraction objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue];

    Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
    if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
    {
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:[thisAttraction objectForKey:@"placeAddress"]
        completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

            // Convert the CLPlacemark to an MKPlacemark
            // Note: There's no error checking for a failed geocode
            CLPlacemark *geocodedPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                                      initWithCoordinate:location
                                      addressDictionary:geocodedPlacemark.addressDictionary];

            // Create a map item for the geocoded address to pass to Maps app
            MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
            [mapItem setName:geocodedPlacemark.name];

            // Set the directions mode to "Driving"
            // Can use MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking instead
            NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};

            // Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
            MKMapItem *currentLocationMapItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];

            // Pass the current location and destination map items to the Maps app
            // Set the direction mode in the launchOptions dictionary
            [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[currentLocationMapItem, mapItem] launchOptions:launchOptions];
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: NSLog the value of `location`.  What is the latitude and longitude?

Comment: @Anna thanks for pointing it out. Actually I found the problem is that I swapped lat/lng data; after correcting this, all is fine. The map would still show with a wrong lat/lng is a little surprizing to me though

Comment: As long as the coordinates were valid, map will show the pin there.  When creating the MKPlacemark, you're setting the coordinate to `location` instead of using the geocoded coordinate in the CLPlacemark.